# How to find a capital letter words from an NLTK corpus using regex?

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk, corpus

I'd like to make a word list with a regular expression which is consists of all capital letters. 
the data set is a bunch of biological theses text files called corpus.

The result for `len(corpus.fileids())` is 487 which means that there are 487 theses in the corpus.

The main reason for this is to collect word list to filter biological words like gene name and etc(ATP, BRCA)

here are some codes that I've been trying. 
(p.s. I'm using python3)

I'm stuck with making functions to call out all files in the corpus.
for a single file, I think this would work.

```
capital = re.findall(r'[A-Z]+', GNICorpus)
```

but the thing is that I have to go through all the words in the theses txt files in the corpus and have no idea. 
1st trial

```
import re
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import*
x = [
    (file)
    for file in Corpus.fileids() 
    for w in Corpus.words(file) 
    if w.upper()
]
```

2nd trial

```
   capital = re.findall(r'[A-Z]+', Corpus)
   capital
```

Third trial

```
for fileid in Corpus.fileids():
    words = Corpus.words(fileid)
    capital = re.findall(r'[A-Z]+', words)
```

Comment: What is `Corpus`? Is it a string? A list of strings?

Comment: Should non-ASCII uppercase letters be included (Ø)?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I added lil more explanation! thank you for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

Your regex would match a single (or many) capital letters in a word.

For example:

```
Corpus = "These are SOME words and someTHAT shouldNot match"
result = re.findall(r'[A-Z]+', Corpus)
>> ['T', 'SOME', 'THAT', 'N']
```

You'd be better off using this regex (where \b is a word boundary):

```
# \b[A-Z]+\b

Corpus = "These are SOME words and someTHAT shouldNot match"
result = re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]+\b', Corpus)
>> ["SOME"]
```

But this all depends on what you are looking for.

Comment: Note that `Corpus` does not seem to be a string in OP code.

Comment: Thank you! But can we make this happen even with the big data sets? I added lil more details in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You might not need a regex for this purpose, but in your use case it's faster =)

## Assuming that the input is a text, this works

```
import re 

text = "These are SOME words and someTHAT shouldNot match"
result = re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]+\b', text)
```

Using https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper, this works too:

```
text = "These are SOME words and someTHAT shouldNot match"
result = [word for word in text.split() if word.isupper()]
```

## Assuming that the `GNICorpus`

From https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/30309207 and most probably from https://github.com/Ewha-Bio/Genomics-Informatics-Corpus

```
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader

root_dir = 'Genomics-Informatics-Corpus/GNI Corpus 1.0'
GNICorpus = PlaintextCorpusReader(root_dir, '.*\.txt', encoding='utf-8')
```

The `GNICorpus` object has a `.raw()` function that will concatenate all files in the object and return a single `str`.

```
>>> type(GNICorpus.raw())
str
```

In that case, the regex can be applied to the raw strings, e.g.

```
re.findall(r'\b[A-Z]+\b', GNICorpus.raw())
```

And to use the `str.isupper` function instead of the regex, it's possible to loop through every token in the corpus object with the `.words()` function, i.e.

```
[word for word in GNICorpus.words() if word.isupper()]
```

You'll find that the regex is much faster than iterating through the `.words()`. There's quite a lot of regex vs Python's native string discussion online, if you're interested.

## But wait! What if we can find "genes sequence" with this approach?

Instead of `[A-Z]`, we can specify the `[ATCG]` sequence:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(re.findall(r'\b[ATCG]+\b', GNICorpus.raw()))
```

[out]:

```
Counter({'G': 1249,
         'CA': 958,
         'A': 6558,
         'CCCTC': 21,
         'C': 2981,
         'T': 1284,
         'CTCT': 3,
         'AG': 64,
         'AACC': 3,
         'AA': 28,
         'CC': 131,
         'TCGA': 122,
         'GT': 427,
         'GAGGGAGGGAGCGAGA': 3,
         'GC': 122,
         'GA': 102,
         'TGACGTCA': 3,
         'TCA': 15,
         'GCG': 4,
         'AGG': 12,
         'ACA': 3,
         'GCA': 3,
         'GTG': 3,
         'AGT': 6,
         'GAA': 3,
         'GAC': 18,
         'AGA': 6,
         'ACC': 7,
         'CTT': 11,
         'TGC': 12,
         'AGC': 3,
         'TCC': 7,
         'TTC': 6,
         'GTT': 4,
         'ACG': 12,
         'ATG': 4,
         'GAG': 9,
         'GGG': 3,
         'AAT': 3,
         'ACAGC': 3,
         'AT': 35,
         'TG': 270,
         'GGTCAACAAATCATAAAGATATTGG': 3,
         'TAAACTTCAGGGTGACCAAAAAATCA': 3,
         'TA': 17,
         'CT': 61,
         'CGC': 20,
         'TC': 100,
         'GG': 23,
         'CG': 15,
         'AC': 6,
         'CCCTCT': 4,
         'TT': 124,
         'CAGT': 3,
         'TCTG': 3,
         'ATCC': 61,
         'AAAAACAACAAGATAA': 3,
         'GATA': 6,
         'CACCC': 3,
         'ATC': 275,
         'GGCGCCATCTT': 3,
         'TCTGAGCC': 3,
         'CGCC': 3,
         'GCTA': 7,
         'AAA': 2,
         'AAG': 30,
         'GTA': 4,
         'ATT': 4,
         'AAC': 4,
         'CAT': 8,
         'GGC': 6,
         'TAA': 6,
         'TTT': 9,
         'CAG': 3,
         'TGG': 3,
         'CCT': 11,
         'CTC': 273,
         'CCG': 12,
         'GCT': 271,
         'TAG': 3,
         'TAT': 7,
         'CAC': 6,
         'TAC': 8,
         'TCG': 3,
         'TTG': 6,
         'ATA': 21,
         'TTAGGG': 3,
         'CACTA': 3,
         'TATA': 19,
         'CCA': 31,
         'CCC': 4,
         'CGT': 3,
         'CGA': 3,
         'CGG': 3,
         'GTC': 268,
         'GGCAGG': 246,
         'CGTGCCCCAGCCCAGTC': 1,
         'TTCCAGTACAGCCCATCCAATAAG': 1,
         'TGCGAGGGCTGCGAGGTC': 1,
         'TGTCAGCTTGCGTGTGGTTGC': 1,
         'GTAACCCGTTGCACCCCATT': 1,
         'CCATCCAATCGGTAGTAGCG': 1,
         'GACGATGCTCCCCGGGCTGTATTC': 1,
         'TCTCTTGCTCTGGGCCTCGTCACC': 1,
         'TCTTAACTGCCGGATCCACAAAAA': 1,
         'ATCTCCGCCAACAGCTTCTCCTTC': 1,
         'GGGCAGCCTCCGTTTGATGGT': 1,
         'CGCTTGGCAGGGTGTTTGGTC': 1,
         'GCCATCGAGGAGTGCCAATACC': 1,
         'GGCCACACCTGCTGAAGAGATG': 1,
         'GTAGCCCCAGTGGAGAGCCTTGTG': 1,
         'ATGCCAGTGGGGAGTTTGTTATCG': 1,
         'TGAATCGGACCCACTTGAGAGG': 1,
         'CAGGAGCGGCTTGTTTGAGGTA': 1,
         'GGAGGCGCCGAGACTTAGGT': 1,
         'GCGGGTGAGCACAGCAGAGC': 1,
         'TCATCCCGAATAAAAGCGAAGAGC': 1,
         'AGGGCAACAACATTAGCAGGAGAT': 1,
         'GATGTGATCCGACATTACA': 1,
         'CTAGAACTGCTCTGTATGT': 1,
         'CAATTCGGCAAGTAATGGA': 1,
         'GTCTCTTCGGGAACTGCAAG': 1,
         'TGGGACACAGGCACTGTAGA': 1,
         'GCTCTCTGCTCCTCCTGTTC': 1,
         'CAATACGACCAAATCCGTTG': 1,
         'ATCG': 10,
         'TCGT': 2,
         'TGAT': 1,
         'CGTG': 1,
         'CGTT': 1,
         'CATC': 1,
         'GTGA': 1,
         'ATCGT': 4,
         'TCGTG': 1,
         'TCGTT': 1,
         'CGTGA': 1,
         'CATCG': 1,
         'GTGAT': 1,
         'CGTGAT': 1,
         'CATCGT': 1,
         'TCGTGA': 1,
         'TCGTGAT': 1,
         'ATCGTGACT': 1,
         'CGTGATT': 2,
         'GTGACT': 1,
         'ATCGTT': 1,
         'ATCGTGAGA': 1,
         'GTGAAG': 1,
         'GTGATTG': 1,
         'GTGATT': 1,
         'TCGTGACT': 3,
         'TCGATTG': 3,
         'TCGTGAGA': 3,
         'TTACT': 3,
         'ACT': 5,
         'ATTG': 2,
         'GATTG': 1,
         'TGTGTAGAGCTCCTCG': 1,
         'TTAAA': 1,
         'GGCG': 1,
         'TACCTGCATGCTGCGGTGAAG': 1,
         'AGGGCTGTGTAGAAGTACTCGC': 1,
         'TTTT': 2,
         'AATAAA': 1,
         'TCGTGCA': 1,
         'TCTACCTCGACAG': 1,
         'CCTCCTCCT': 1,
         'CCTTGGTTTTC': 1,
         'GAAATCCCATCACCATCTTCCAGG': 1,
         'GAGCCCCAGCCTTCTCCATG': 1,
         'AACACCA': 1,
         'CGCTCCCGCCTTACTTCGCA': 1,
         'TTAGCTTGCCTCGTCCCC': 1,
         'TTTCGACACTGGATGGCG': 1,
         'TTGCGTTGCGTAGGGGGGAT': 1,
         'TTTAAA': 2,
         'GATATC': 1,
         'AGTATC': 1,
         'CGTCTGTGAGGGGAGCGTTT': 1,
         'TGATTTTGATGACGAGCGTAAT': 1,
         'GATGTGAGAACTGTATCCTAGCAAG': 1,
         'GGCTGGCCTGTTGAACAAGTCTGGA': 1,
         'ATAC': 1,
         'GTCGGAGTCAACGGATTTG': 1,
         'TGGGTGGAATCA': 1,
         'TATTGGA': 1,
         'AGAAAAAGCAACCACGAAGC': 1,
         'AAACCTCTGTCTGTGAGTGCC': 1,
         'TATT': 1,
         'ACCC': 1,
         'GCCA': 15,
         'CAAT': 1,
         'AGAC': 11,
         'GCTCCCGCCTTACTTCGCAT': 1,
         'CGGGGACGAGGCAAGCTAA': 1,
         'GCCGCCATCCAGTGTCG': 1,
         'TTGCGTTGCGTAGGGGGG': 1})
```

## What if I want to set a minimum no. of character sequence?

If we want to set the minimum character to 4, instead of `+`, you can use `{4,}`:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(re.findall(r'\b[ATCG]{4,}\b', GNICorpus.raw()))
```